# How to change jQuery code to hide .jpg at the end of the url?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Could someone help me with this short piece of code?
Right now when I click thumbnail image on my site it creates url in the address bar. But url has .jpg at the end. 
How should I modify the code so that it won't show .jpg at the end of the url?

This piece of code also opens Colorbox image automatically if user enters site with url like www.domain.com/#image.jpg so naturally the change to the code should affect also to that.

Thanks!

```
jQuery(function() {
    var id, group;

    group = jQuery("a[rel='lightbox[63]']").colorbox({ 
        onComplete: function() {
            window.location.hash = (this.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [,''])[1];
        }, 
        onClosed: function() {
            location.hash = '';
        }
    });

    id = location.hash.replace(/^\#/, '');
    group.filter('[href$="'+id+'"]').eq(0).click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
window.location.hash = (this.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [,''])[1];
```

With this:

```
// Get the image URL
with_ext = (this.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [,''])[1];
// Get the image url without the extension
without_ext =   with_ext.substring(0, with_ext.lastIndexOf(".")));
// Redirect
window.location.hash = without_ext;
```

### Explanation

- `my_str.lastIndexOf(".")` returns the position of the last `.` character in the string `my_str`
- `my_str.substring(n, m)`, where `n` and `m` are numbers returns the characters in a `my_str` beginning at `n` through `m` characters - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

### Example

http://jsbin.com/uqufev/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
It works now if I click the image but when typing the url manually (without the .jpg at the end) it won't open the image automatically. Any idea how to implement also that?

Comment: Please link to your page. (PS: SA is not a forum, it's a QA site, so if your answer is solved and you have another question, please ask a new question separately, you will probably get better answers that way).